# Unable to retrieve dictionary data from Userdefaults in Swift 3

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift3, xcode8, userdefaults

Do you guys can bring some light on the use of dictionaries with UserDefaults ?

What I want to get is to pass a certain dictionary from a view controller to another one using UserDefaults.

```
var dict = [String : AnyObject?]()
dict = ["Name": "Henri", "Group": "A", "Category": "4"]
UserDefaults.standard.set.(dict, forKey: "MyDict")
```

Then I try to retrieve the data

```
let retrieveDict = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey:"MyDict")
```

I got a nice **nil** answer in the console. When I try with int or float types it is fine... Is there anything I am missing to make this dictionary ?

Comment: It should be `UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "MyDict")`

Comment: UserDefaults is a terrible way to pass data between view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code won't compile.

Second, a dictionary with type `[String, AnyObject?]` make no sense because you'll be not able to set `nil` in UserDefaults. You should use empty String maybe for that purpose.

The working code could look like that :

```
    var dict = [String : Any]() // or maybe [String : String] if you sure about value type
    dict = ["Name": "Henri", "Group": "A", "Category": "4"]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "MyDict")
    let retrieveDict = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey:"MyDict")
```

Hope it helps you :)